# jetty configuration: what is "lowThreads"?

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, threadpool

I'm writing a jetty configuration file, and I haven't been able to find information about a thread pooling parameter.

My aim is to tune jetty for performance, and I would like to understand what the "lowThreads" item means for a ThreadPool object.

Up to now, I've found that it's used to ["set the low resource threads threshold"](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html#setLowThreads%28int%29),
and that it tells the server that ["under that threshold the pool will be considered low on threads"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Walkthrough+jetty.xml).

But it's not straightforward. What being considered "low on thread" means and what are the consequences on the behaviour of jetty?

(I'm using jetty 6.1.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a threshold to determine whether the thread pool is low on resources (if queued connections > lowThreads) which will cause Jetty to apply lowResourceMaxIdleTime as [socket SO timeout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int))